# Authorization issue when trying to get build work items

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to get the work items related to build in Azure DevOps. The PAT token has full access and it is throwing an authorization error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-work-items-refs-from-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

```
var attachment = buildClient.GetBuildWorkItemsRefsFromCommitsAsync(oenum, projectName, buildRunId).Result;
```

Error log:

```
VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClientCompatBase.<SendAsync>d__44`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClientCompatBase.<SendAsync>d__43`1.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

> VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.

First you can use the PAT to directly run the Rest API: [Builds - Get Build Work Items Refs From Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-work-items-refs-from-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

If it can work fine, this means that the PAT has enough permissions to run the API.

In this case, you can clean the **cached credentials in VS** and run your code again.

Here are the steps:

1. Execute **regedit**
2. clean key(s) under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp`
3. restart VS
4. run your project with the PAT.

[image]

Or you can navigate to  `C:\Users\username(Team Explorer user name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache` and remove the cache folder to clear the cached credentials.